# Accessing value within a div tag for an @if statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got a CSHTML page that calls a Javascript file which populates`('#product-name')`

I can have a div tag that displays the value within that element `<div id="product-name"/>` (I'm new to Razor and currently do not have access to the controller or modeller, just the CSHTML page)

How can I access the value in an @if statement. EG:

```
@if(product-name='Product One')
{do product one}
else
{do product two}
```

Comment: `$('#product-name').text()` will return the value in the `<div>` element

Comment: Thanks Stephen - so would it just be `@if($('product-name').text() == 'Product One' { do something }` then?

Comment: `if($('#product-name').text() == 'Product One')) { .... }` (you need the `#` to identify it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke are you sure we can use `$('#product-name').text()` in razor statements?

Comment: @PavanTeja, You right (didn't spot it was in a razor statement). Not sure what OP is trying to do

Comment: @Mike how does `product-name` values comes to page? from ajax call or from ViewModel in pageload

Comment: @Mike, If your setting the value in javascript, then you need to access using javascript (razor code is server side code)

Comment: @PavanTeja - it is an Ajax call within the JS file.

Comment: then you have to use javasript.not razor

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your viewmodel property for "product-name" if you want to do the conditional in razor. However, you can achieve this all from the same javascript that you populate product-name from:

```
..
if ($('#product-name').text() == 'Product One')){
    productOne.show();
...
```

and you need two hidden divs:

```
<div id="productOne" style="display: none;"/>
<div id="productTwo" style="display: none;"/>
```